# SQL Recursion with original table

Tags: sql-server

I have a leveled recursion question. I have a table called Item with some values, as well as an n..n table for Item that Extends an item. The structure is as follows:

```
ITEM [id, Name]

ItemLinksToItem [ID, ItemChildID, ItemParentID]
```

Now I want to make a level-list of items with a CTE recursion, but I need the items in that have no children (therefore aren't in the ItemLinksToItem) in there as well.
If using basic recursion, it just links the ItemLinksToItem itemchildid to itemparentid.

```
with cte as(
select 
a.ItemChildID, a.ItemParentId, 1 as level
from ItemLinksToItem a
union all
select 
c.ItemChildID, p.ItemParentId, p.level +1
from ItemLinksToItem c
inner join cte p on p.ItemChildID = c.ItemParentId
)
select * from cte
```

resulting in the following information:

```
ItemChildID                             ItemParentID                            Level
D8B11945-DC40-4E95-925E-7B38EB795510    E40FB8AB-0A06-496C-B004-B5B7044564E5    1
E40FB8AB-0A06-496C-B004-B5B7044564E5    2399F47A-056C-ED11-9FC3-B2E1592D478C    1
D8B11945-DC40-4E95-925E-7B38EB795510    2399F47A-056C-ED11-9FC3-B2E1592D478C    2
```

But I also want all items that are not in the ItemLinkstoItem in there with ItemParentID, no ItemChildID and Level 0, as such

```
ItemChildID                             ItemParentID                            Level
D8B11945-DC40-4E95-925E-7B38EB795510    E40FB8AB-0A06-496C-B004-B5B7044564E5    1
E40FB8AB-0A06-496C-B004-B5B7044564E5    2399F47A-056C-ED11-9FC3-B2E1592D478C    1
D8B11945-DC40-4E95-925E-7B38EB795510    2399F47A-056C-ED11-9FC3-B2E1592D478C    2
NULL                                    9859AFC6-D505-4199-9298-3CAD55B6EB67    0
```

Can anyone help me out?
Example data below

```
declare @Item table (id uniqueidentifier, 
                        name nvarchar(255))

insert into @Item VALUES
('D8B11945-DC40-4E95-925E-7B38EB795510', 'Item Zero'),
('E40FB8AB-0A06-496C-B004-B5B7044564E5', 'Item One'),
('2399F47A-056C-ED11-9FC3-B2E1592D478C', 'Item Two'),
('C43CF1D6-50E9-4DFF-A28C-DF0CEAEDF405', 'Unrelated Item Three')

declare @ItemLinksToItem table (id int, 
                                itemchildid uniqueidentifier , 
                                itemparentid uniqueidentifier)
INSERT INTO @ItemLinksToItem
VALUES
(5, 'D8B11945-DC40-4E95-925E-7B38EB795510', 'E40FB8AB-0A06-496C-B004-B5B7044564E5'),
(4, 'E40FB8AB-0A06-496C-B004-B5B7044564E5', '2399F47A-056C-ED11-9FC3-B2E1592D478C')
```

Comment: Please include samples data from both of the tables

Comment: @Squirrel added example data as per request.

Comment: It could be an over simplification of your problem, but one solution might be to just add a union to your final select and select items with no records in the linked item table - [Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sVNrHxC9)?

Comment: It works, but I was hoping to do it in the CTE.

Comment: Why were you hoping to do it in the CTE? It can be done by altering your anchor query ([further example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tXjFNDrl)), but I am not convinced it would be more efficient